# PHP color wheel

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm creating a function that allows the user to use a color wheel and change the color of a graph,  I have the function for set color below in html

```
function setColor(){

var heat = document.createElement("INPUT");
heat.setAttribute("type", "color");
document.body.appendChild(heat);
}
```

ideally I would love to change  red and green low and high  in php

```
 var low = setColor();
 var high = setColor();
 var colorscaleValue = [
 [0, "red"],
 [1, "green"]
  ];
```

I've used a php function 
 to try to set it but it doesn't seem to work any help?

Comment: Why do you want to change red/green with php? You know that PHP is a server side scripting language. So if you need to change colors for visibility purposes dynamically in the browser, javascript will be the language to go with. If you need to save the chosen colors or fetch them from a server thats where you will need PHP. In which case do the colors change? On a click somewhere or what is the idea?

Comment: Look what I found on The Google: http://jscolor.com/